# API Blueprint Data Structures Enum Output to Schema

Tags: apiblueprint, aglio

I have defined an Enum at Data Structures and then compile with `aglio`. The output schema somehow adds a `null`. How can I get rid of that `null`?

```
## StatusType (enum[string])
+ Verified
+ Unverified
+ VerifiedLikely
+ Invalid
```

But at the generated schema after compiling using `aglio`.

```
"status": {
  "enum": [
    null,
    "Verified",
    "Unverified",
    "VerifiedLikely",
    "Invalid"
  ]
}
```